# Sorting Array not functioning correctly C++

Tags: c++

So, I have been writing a sorting loop for my program. It automatically sorts Arrays and has done it in the past efficently.
That being said, once I added it into my American Football Manager program, things did not work out so effectively.

So below, I will provide a working version of this sorting loop, and then after the Football Manager version which isn't working.

Here is the working one...

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <time.h> 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
    int i, j,temp;
    int values[10] = { 7, 4, 2, 8, 1, 3, 9, 6, 10, 5 };  // array of 10 'int' values

    int values_count = sizeof(values) / sizeof(int); // 'sizeof' returns the number of 'int' values in the array (10)
cout << values_count;
    printf ("Unsorted...\n");

    for (i = 0; i < values_count; i++)
        printf("element %2d: %2d\n", i, values[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < values_count - 1; i++) // loop from 0 to 8 (the first element is values[0]; 10th is values[9])
    {
        // Compare values[i] with each element from values[i+1] to the values[9] (indexed in the inner loop by 'j').
        // After executing the inner loop, values[i]is now assured to be less than any from values[i+1] to values[9]. 

        for (j = i + 1; j < values_count; j++) // When i=0, loop from 1-9; When i=1, loop from 2-9; When i=2, loop from 3-9, etc.
        {
            // We are sorting to get 'least-to-greatest'. So, any 'values' array elememnt values[j] beyond values[i] 
            // (outer loop) that is greater than values[i] is swapped with the [i] postition in the array

            if (values[j] < values[i])
            {
                temp = values[i];
                values[i] = values[j];
                values[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSorted...\n");

    for (i = 0; i < values_count; i++)
        printf("element %2d: %2d\n", i, values[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

That one works perfectly. Here is the second that is failing...

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <time.h> 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
class Team{
public:
    int wins, losses;
    
};



Team teams[10];
int team_count = 10;
int j, i, temp;

teams[1].wins = 1;
teams[2].wins = 2;
teams[3].wins = 5;
teams[4].wins = 3;
teams[5].wins = 6;
teams[6].wins = 10;
teams[7].wins = 7;
teams[8].wins = 4;
teams[9].wins = 8;
teams[10].wins = 9;

for (i = 0; i < team_count; i++){

    printf("element %2d: %2d\n", i, teams[i].wins);

    for (i = 0; i < team_count - 1; i++) // loop from 0 to 8 (the first element is values[0]; 10th is values[9])
    {
        // Compare values[i] with each element from teams[i+1] to the teams[9] (indexed in the inner loop by 'j').
        // After executing the inner loop, teams[i]is now assured to be less than any from teams[i+1] to teams[9]. 

        for (j = i + 1; j < team_count; j++) // When i=0, loop from 1-9; When i=1, loop from 2-9; When i=2, loop from 3-9, etc.
        {
            // We are sorting to get 'least-to-greatest'. So, any 'teams' array elememnt teams[j] beyond teams[i] 
            // (outer loop) that is greater than teams[i] is swapped with the [i] postition in the array

            if (teams[j].wins < teams[i].wins)
            {
                temp = teams[i].wins;
                teams[i].wins = teams[j].wins;
                teams[j].wins = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}









}
```

This is the output I get for the second version...

element  0: 4253632

---

Process exited after 0.08073 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Help appreciated

Comment: You didn't initialize `teams[0].wins` and you did out-of-bounds write `teams[10].wins = 9;`.

Comment: Also the inner loop modifies `i` and it is preventing the outer loop from working well.

Comment: For `Team teams[10];` valid array indicies are 0 .. 9 not 1 .. 10.

Comment: Compile with `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined` and the compiler will tell your what to fix.

Comment: Thanks for catching my newbie mistake xD. Though, even with this change it doesn't work, it only outputs the first element.

Comment: Shouldn't `teams[x].losses` be sorted according to wins?

Comment: If it is the inner loop modifying i, it worked on the first version, and not my second?

Comment: There are no nested loops that use the same loop variable in the first version. There are one in the second version. In the other words, there are no inner loop that modify `i` in the first version.

Comment: You are printing the wins in the wrong place

Comment: Your first and second loop try to iterate over the same integer `i`. Hence the first will not run the expected number of times.

Comment: how could I change this? Sorry, I'm pretty new to C++

Comment: @TroyCox Have a look at [reliable resources for learning C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/430766) and throw out whatever you are using right now. Browsing the [`[C++-faq]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) tag here on SO might also be helpful.

Comment: Unrelated: This odious bit of code `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` [should never be directly included in a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), and the way it's being used demonstrates that you don't properly understand what it is supposed to do. Be very careful when using stuff without understanding how to use it. C++ is an exceptionally unforgiving language.

Comment: Well I ain't gonna throw out my granddad xD. I just started programming and he is a software engineer for HP so he teaches me. Is there a simple way I can fix this problem?

Comment: Don't throw out your granddad :) But keep in mind that a good engineer is not necessarily a good teacher. Regarding fixing the issue, you have been given two proper answers that address your issue.

Comment: Also note that C++ is a pretty fast-moving language. Stuff is betting added, mostly for the better, all the time. For example, as of the 2017 revision `int values_count = sizeof(values) / sizeof(int);` could be `int values_count = std::size(values);` and since `values` is an array `std::size`  should be a compile time constant, so there's no need to cache it in a variable. You can call `std::size(values)` as you need it with no performance hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are problems of the second code:

- Non-standard unused headers are included and they are preventing the code from working in some environments.
- `teams[0].wins` is used without being initialized.
- `teams[10].wins = 9;` cause dangerous out-of-range access.
- The sorting routine is accidentally put in the printing routine.
- Only `wins` are sorted, not `losses`, and it will break the information.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    class Team{
    public:
        int wins, losses;
        
    };

    Team teams[10];
    int team_count = 10;
    int j, i;

    teams[0].wins = 1;
    teams[1].wins = 2;
    teams[2].wins = 5;
    teams[3].wins = 3;
    teams[4].wins = 6;
    teams[5].wins = 10;
    teams[6].wins = 7;
    teams[7].wins = 4;
    teams[8].wins = 8;
    teams[9].wins = 9;

    for (i = 0; i < team_count; i++){
        printf("element %2d: %2d\n", i, teams[i].wins);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < team_count - 1; i++) // loop from 0 to 8 (the first element is values[0]; 10th is values[9])
    {
        // Compare values[i] with each element from teams[i+1] to the teams[9] (indexed in the inner loop by 'j').
        // After executing the inner loop, teams[i]is now assured to be less than any from teams[i+1] to teams[9]. 

        for (j = i + 1; j < team_count; j++) // When i=0, loop from 1-9; When i=1, loop from 2-9; When i=2, loop from 3-9, etc.
        {
            // We are sorting to get 'least-to-greatest'. So, any 'teams' array elememnt teams[j] beyond teams[i] 
            // (outer loop) that is greater than teams[i] is swapped with the [i] postition in the array

            if (teams[j].wins < teams[i].wins)
            {
                Team temp = teams[i];
                teams[i] = teams[j];
                teams[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < team_count; i++){
        printf("element %2d: %2d\n", i, teams[i].wins);
    }

}
```

Comment: While you're at it, you could pull the iteration variable inside the loop-scope (and fix their type) :)

Comment: @bitmask Fix their type? How?

Comment: `int` is a rubbish type for an index variable. Although 10 is guaranteed to fit into every platform's `int`, it is a bad habit and it **will** break one's neck eventually. The index type for sequence containers (such as arrays) is `std::size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: One more thing, how can I call like the top two numbers? Say the top two teams play a championship game, I want the computer to know which teams are the top two. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: The array is sorted in ascending order, so take the last two elements (`teams[team_count - 1]` and `teams[team_count - 2]`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much simpler way:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(std::begin(teams), std::end(teams),
    [](const Team& left, const Team& right) {
        return left.wins < right.wins;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort) solution (untested code)

```
ranges::sort(std::begin(teams), std::end(teams), &Team::wins);
```

I have waited so long for this ... this might even work

```
ranges::sort(teams, &Team::wins);
```